# Erlang Concurrency Model

Tags: erlang

This could be a very basic question but is Erlang capable of calling a method on another prcoess and wait for it to repond back with some object type without sleeping threads?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're *waiting* for an answer, the calling process will have to sleep eventually… But that's no big deal.

While processes are stuck on the `receive` loop, other processes can work. In fact, it's not uncommon to have thousands of processes just waiting for messages. And since Erlang processes are not true OS threads, they're very lightweight so the performance loss is minimal.

In fact, the way sleep is implemented looks like:

```
sleep(Milliseconds) ->
    receive
        % Intentionally left empty
    after Milliseconds -> ok
    end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to peek into the mailbox if that is what you mean. Say we have sent a message to another process and now we want to see if the other process has sent something back to us. But we don't want to *block* on the receive:

```
 receive
    Pattern -> Body;
    Pattern2 -> Body2
 after 0 ->
    AfterBody
 end
```

will try to match against the `Pattern` and `Pattern2` in the mailbox. If none matches, it will immediately time out and go to `AfterBody`. This allows you to implement a non-blocking peek into the mailbox.

If the process is a `gen_server` the same thing can be had by playing with the internal state and the `Timeout` setting when a callback returns to the `gen_server`'s control. You can set a Timeout of `0` to achieve this.

Comment: *I GIVE CRAP ANSWERS* answering *Mike Dotnet*. What's the world coming to?

Answer (score 0):

What am getting from the question is that we are talking of `Synchronous Message Passing`. YES ! Erlang can do this perfectly well, its the most basic way of handling concurrency in Erlang. Consider this below:

```
rpc(Request, To)->
  MySelf = self(),
  To ! {MySelf,Request},
  receive
     {To,Reply} -> Reply
  after timer:seconds(5) -> erlang:exit({error,timedout})
  end.
```

The code above shows that a processes sends a message to another and immediately goes into waiting (for a reply) without having to sleep. If it does not  get a reply within 5 seconds, it will exit.